# How to teach findbugs to understand IoC fields properly?

Tags: java, findbugs

This is my class (JAX-RS annotated):

```
@Path("/")
public class Foo {
  @Context
  private UriInfo uriInfo;
  // ...
}
```

This is what [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) says:

```
Unwritten field: com.XXX.Foo.uriInfo
```

It's true, the field is unwritten, but it is injected by JAX-RS servlet. I think that I'm doing something wrong here, but how to solve the problem?

Comment: You could try just suppressing the warning…

Comment: @Donal Well, of course, I can even disable findbugs validation at all. But the point is not to turn validation off, but to understand how to write safe and secure code. Findbugs and his warnings are designed to help in this, as far as I understand. Right?

Comment: That's why I didn't make that into an answer. (You could also ask the Findbugs developers about this directly; the `@Context` annotation is retained at runtime and so can be spotted by their analyzer. OTOH, when things get complex e.g. with Spring, it's *still* better to do it a different way that Findbugs won't get so upset about.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've understand so far is that findbugs is right. It tells me that this variable is not accessible from outside of the class, and my annotation is not valid in terms of OOP. The JAX-RS servlet will have to break field access restrictions in order to inject `UriInfo`. I have to give him a legal way to this field:

```
@Path("/")
public class Foo {
  private UriInfo uriInfo;
  @Context
  public void setUriInfo(UriInfo info) {
    this.uriInfo = info;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Now it's correct for findbugs and for OOP design paradigm :)

Comment: ...and how's it affecting your test coverage? ;-)